# Assertion in Data Driven Testing in soapUI Free version

Tags: groovy, soapui, assertion, data-driven-tests

I am doing Data driven test in soapuI free version with 4 data sets. i have 3 Teststeps that includes: 2 groovy script and one Login REST Service. i have performed assertion in Login Teststep. MY question is what to do if assertion fails for any data then i do not want to go ahead with rest of data sets.
Reason behind this is I am not able to conclude at the end of run that for which data our test fails.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

In the testcase options (the knife and fork button), turn on "Fail on error".